# "improved strictly" or "strictly improved "?

Tags: grammar

I recent wrote a sentence (see below) to reply to the editor of a journal, I am not sure if I correctly placed **strictly**  in the right place, that is, **improved strictly** or **strictly improved**? Which one is better?

> Meanwhile, we have polished our English throughout the paper and the reference format is **improved strictly** according to the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence is changed slightly by the placement of strictly.  I think the best way to phrase the sentence so it is clear and unambiguous would be to say

> ... the reference format **has been** improved **by according strictly** to the IEEE standard.

if you mean that *the improvement happened by means of according closely to the standard*.  "Has been" sounds better than "is", because the action of improving it happened at an unspecified time before now, and it matches tense better with the *have polished* earlier in the sentence.

Let's look at some possible word orders and how they change the meaning slightly.

> ...strictly improved according...

implies that the improvement was strict.  This is probably not what we mean.

> ...improved strictly according...

implies that the improvement was only in the opinion of the standard of the IEEE.

But if we use *by according strictly*, we give the sense that the improvement happened by means of according.